# Elegant solution for exploring large number of true/false properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is a pretty ubiquitous problem, but my specific use case is building a "friendly" filter name based on an object that contains true/false settings.

Here is an example of one of these settings objects

```
var settings = {
    includeMen: true,
    includeWomen: false,
    includeDependents: true,
}
```

The amateur solution would be a big set of `if` statments like

```
if(settings.includeMen && settings.includeWomen && settings.includeDependents){
    return "All People"
}

if(settings.includeMen && !settings.includeWomen && settings.includeDependents){
    return "Men and Children"
}

if(settings.includeMen && settings.includeWomen && !settings.includeDependents){
    return "Men and Women"
}
...
```

Any less amateurish ideas?
(Project is using Lodash if that helps)

Comment: Why is it an amateur solution? It's as clear as it gets and shows the possible outcomes.

Comment: In this example, maybe that's acceptable, but if there were 8 or more properties this would be unreadable and enormous

Comment: Maybe an elegant solution using bitwise operators and use the boolean flags combinations as binary numbers. But danger of `magic numbers`, so make sure it is super well-documented... **Edit:** If you want it more scalable I would just use TypeScript ;D.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Nesting the ifs and splitting the logic into a few methods would make it more clear, but I'd say just keep it simple. As long as you keep the logic all in one class/ module to adhere to the single responsibility principle , there's no problem with it in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 const {includeMen, includeWomen, includeDependents} = settings;

 const result = [];
 if(includeMen) result.push("Men");
 if(includeWomen) result.push("Women");
 if(includeDependents) result.push("Children");

 if(result.length === 3)
   return "All people";
 if(!result.length)
   return "No one";

 return result.join(" and ");
```

If you want to have custom output for each case instead, you could do some funny bitshifting:

```
const {includeMen, includeWomen, includeDependents} = settings;

return [
 "No one",
 "Children",
 "Women",
 "Children and Women",
 "Men",
 "Men and Children",
 "Men and Women",
"All people"
][+includeDependents + (includeWomen << 1) + (includeMen << 2)];
```

*(Disclaimer: Your teammates will hate you if you do this :))*

Comment: *Disclaimer: Your teammates will hate you if you do this*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a lot of ways,
probably I would transform the object keys on the run and then make the string:

```js
var settings = {
    includeMen: true,
    includeWomen: false,
    includeDependents: true,
}

var trueFields = Object.entries(settings).reduce((ac, [k, v]) => 
  v ? 
  [...ac, k.replace(/^include/,'')] :
  ac
,[])

var str = !trueFields.length ?
  'nobody ...' :
  trueFields.join(' and ')


console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example of what I mentioned in the comment about transforming multiple `booleans` to- and- from binary with bitwise operators from [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> ## Automate Mask Creation
>
> You can create multiple masks from a set of
>   Boolean values, like this:

```js
function createMask() {
  var nMask = 0,
    nFlag = 0,
    nLen = arguments.length > 32 ? 32 : arguments.length;
  for (nFlag; nFlag < nLen; nMask |= arguments[nFlag] << nFlag++);
  return nMask;
}
var mask1 = createMask(true, true, false, true); // 11, i.e.: 1011
var mask2 = createMask(false, false, true); // 4, i.e.: 0100
var mask3 = createMask(true); // 1, i.e.: 0001
// etc.

alert(mask1); // prints 11, i.e.: 1011
```

> ### Reverse algorithm: an array of booleans from a mask
>
> If you want to create an `Array` of `Booleans` from a mask you can use this code:
>
> ```
> function arrayFromMask(nMask) {
>   // nMask must be between -2147483648 and 2147483647
>   if (nMask > 0x7fffffff || nMask < -0x80000000) { 
>     throw new TypeError('arrayFromMask - out of range'); 
>   }
>   for (var nShifted = nMask, aFromMask = []; nShifted; 
>        aFromMask.push(Boolean(nShifted & 1)), nShifted >>>= 1);
>   return aFromMask;
> }
>
> var array1 = arrayFromMask(11);
> var array2 = arrayFromMask(4);
> var array3 = arrayFromMask(1);
>
> alert('[' + array1.join(', ') + ']');
> // prints "[true, true, false, true]", i.e.: 11, i.e.: 1011
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The variety of answers you have indicate that there isn't one de facto correct way of achieving this.  My approach would be to create an array of filter name definitions that is both easy to read and edit, and can be searched through for a matching name.

The reason I like this approach is that when new filters are added, with new names, there is no need to edit the logic that does the searching. Just add a new definition to the list of filter names.

This 1) reduces the chances of introducing bugs, 2) encapsulates the complexity within an easily testable and rarely changing function, and 3) is pretty obvious to team members what is happening.

```js
const SETTING_PREFIX = "include";

const removeInclude = k => k.substr(SETTING_PREFIX.length, k.length);

const isTrue = x => !!x;
const isFalse = x => !x;

const getFilteredProps = (filter, predicate) => {
  return Object.keys(filter).filter(k =>
    predicate(filter[k])
  )
}

const getFilterName = filter => {
  const trueFilterProps = getFilteredProps(filter, isTrue).map(removeInclude);
  const falseFilterProps = getFilteredProps(filter, isFalse).map(removeInclude);;
  
  const filterNameDefinition = filterNames.find(definition => 
    trueFilterProps.every(key =>
        definition[0].includes(key)
    ) &&
    falseFilterProps.every(key =>
        !definition[0].includes(key)
    )
  );
  
  if (!filterNameDefinition) {
    return "Unnamed filter";
  }
  
  return filterNameDefinition[0].join(" and ");
}

const settings = {
  includeMen: false,
  includeWomen: true,
  includeDependents: true
};

const filterNames = [
  [["Men", "Women", "Dependents"], "All People"],
  [["Men", "Dependents"], "Men and Children"]
];

console.log(getFilterName(settings))
```